# BLE slave logic to increase battery duration

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, ads, battery

I'm looking for answers on the net for 2 days, and it seems like I can't find my answer so I finally post it here hoping I just mess something.
I'm conceiving a BLE slave device to log humidity in a room twice a day. This device has to run for at least 2 Years before getting recharged.

What is the BLE logic to ensure long battery life ?

1) Is a long advertisement / connection interval enough ?

2) Do I need to implement a RTC with interrupt to wake up my device and start advertising to get connected?

3) Do I have to use advertising packets only, and include my data into it?

I think I just miss something about bluetooth low energy, and it is a problem to create a ble device.

Thank you very much for you help, and have a good day !

Answer (score 0):

You could calculate power consumption at https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/power/ for Nordic's chip. If the device does not advertise or has an active connection (i.e. it's just sleeping), it consumes almost no power at all and will definitely run for 2 years even on a CR2016 battery. So if possible, if you have for example a button that can start the advertising only when needed, that would be good.

Otherwise if you want it to be always available you must advertise. How long the advertisement interval should be depends on how long connection setup latency you want. If you have a BLE scanner that scans 100% of the time the advertisement interval will be equal to the connection setup time. If you have a low-power BLE scanner that only scans for example 10% of the time you'll have to multiply your advertitsement interval by 10 to get the expected setup time. It all comes down to simple math :)

I'd suggest create a connection rather than just putting the data in the advertisement packets since then you can acknowledge that the data has been arrived.

Note that if you have a connection interval of 4 seconds and have a stable constant connection you can get several years battery time on a coin cell battery.

Comment: Thank you for your answmer Emil !

If you said my device has an active connection, you mean if it stays connected with a long connection interval right ?
My device can't have any button to start advertising, so I guess It has to advertise each time first to post datas (since there is not only one slave)
About latency and connection setup, I have no requirements, so I could use max lengh defined in BLE specs?
 Thanks again for your help !

Comment: And have you ever heard about a RTC that wakes up the device twice a day to initiate advertisement and data post ? My master device would have a internet connection so It can scan for 10 minutes continuously waiting for slave. I thought this could ensure a better battery life than a 4 sec interval since I have to post twice a day only.

Anyway thanks for your help, It eases me to be sure I didn't miss something about connection logic :)

Comment: Yes that will also work, if you know the master device will always be available.

Comment: Great ! Thank you very much for your help, very usefull :)